# How to check table results on multiple pages using selenium

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to use selenium to check that a table on the page has a particular string.

I am trying to use "Table Should Contain". Does this check all the pages of result or only the results displayed on the current page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use isElementPresent() or isVisible() functions

2) You can get the css for the entire table and do a search for the particular string you're searching for.

Option 2 tends to be faster, but I don't know how the table on the page works, so the string might be in the css selector even though its not actually displayed on the page.